# Citrix causing WPF sizing problems?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, citrix

I just deployed my first Windows app (using WPF/.NET 4) to our Citrix environment here at the office. However, when it is run, the DataGrids inside windows are much wider than in my Windows 7 dev env (or any Windows desktop env I've tested), so the right side of the DataGrid gets hidden, requiring a scroll bar to appear where there was none before.  Is this a Citrix "issue"?  Am I laying out my Windows incorrectly to account for this difference?  Windows .NET updates which are missing?  Thanks for any suggestions here.

(Citrix Env: Running XenApp 6.5 on Server 2008 R2)

Here is my Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TableMaint.ItemClassExtrasEdit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TableMaint"
        Title="Edit Item Class Extra Fields" Height="600" Width="331" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="300"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid Height="59" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Save" Height="23" Name="OKButton" Width="75" Margin="0,0,6,18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    IsDefault="True" Click="OKButton_Click" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,101,18" Name="CancelButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" 
                    IsCancel="True" />
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="ExtrasGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserReorderColumns="False"  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="20" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:NullCheckBoxConverter x:Key="nullCheckBoxConverter"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="    Item Class ID    " Binding="{Binding ItemClassID}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding ItemClassName}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Foo1" Binding="{Binding Foo1, Converter={StaticResource nullCheckBoxConverter}}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Foo2" Binding="{Binding Foo2, Converter={StaticResource nullCheckBoxConverter}}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Foo3" Binding="{Binding Foo3, Converter={StaticResource nullCheckBoxConverter}}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Foo4" Binding="{Binding Foo4, Converter={StaticResource nullCheckBoxConverter}}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: `Am I laying out my Windows incorrectly to account for this difference?` - Impossible to know without seeing some relevant XAML.

Comment: @HighCore - I added the XAML for the Window.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little testing and I got slightly wider columns when running under Citrix. It was even a little wider running through a Citrix session than when running via RDP on the same machine. It looks like the font used in the data grid headers is bigger for some reason when running under Citrix.

This is the kind of stuff that you would normally configure as user via: Personalize - Windows Color and Appearance. I don't know why it's different in Citrix sessions, I've never really noticed this before myself. I'd just try and work around this slight variance myself. You could ask around on the Citrix forums, XenApp 6.5 forum is here:

http://forums.citrix.com/category.jspa?categoryID=289

It might be possible to override whatever the XenApp server is doing by locking down the window settings via GPO.

Comment: I will check over in that forum - thanks. Also glad to hear it's not just me!